# Why is my Django form is not displaying anything?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am following a tutorial in which we will create a form to hold simple object parameters.

Here's the code:

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Item

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['item_name', 'item_desc', 'item_price', 'item_image']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    item_desc = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    item_price = models.IntegerField()
    item_image = models.CharField(max_length=500, default ="https://i.jamesvillas.co.uk/images/jvh/holiday-destinations/resort/food-placeholder.jpg" )
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('item/', views.item, name = 'item'),
    path('info/', views.info, name = "info"),
    path('<int:item_id>/', views.detail, name = "detail" ),
    #add form
    path('add', views.create_item, name = "create"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Item
from django.template import loader
from .forms import ItemForm
#Some code here

def create_item(request):
    form = ItemForm(request.POST or None)

    if (form.is_valid()):
        form.save()
        return redirect('food/index')

    return render(request, 'food/item-form.html', {'form': form})
```

**food/item-form.html**

```
<form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type= "Submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

Now when I go to http://localhost:8000/food/add, it displays an empty page! I have followed the tutorial the exact same way then why is My project not working?

Comment: What's the folder structure of your food app? Is your template really at food/item-form.html? or is it at food/templates/food/item-form.html?

Comment: Any of your templates working or getting diplayed?

Comment: @Asher The food app has a templates folder which has a food directory and in it, item-form.html exists.

Comment: @user6837382 all other templates are working!

Comment: path('add/', add slash there and check

Comment: @user6837382 I don't know how, but the code suddenly started working on its own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: its because you added slash

Answer (score 0):

correct your views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
else:
    form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It still does not display anything